# Generating multiple plots containing functions in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make a composite plot in R using the packages ggplot2 and ggpubr.
I have no problem in making the composite plots except each plot has a normal distribution curve specific to that dataset. When I generate the composite plot, both plots have the same curve, that of the last dataset.

How can I generate the composite plot with each plot having its own specific normal distribution curve?

**CODE AND OUTPUT PLOTS**

```
## PLOT 1 ##

results_matrix_C <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=20))
colnames(results_matrix_C) <- c("X")

m <- mean(results_matrix_C$X)
sd <- sd(results_matrix_C$X)
dnorm_C <- function(x){
  norm_C <- dnorm(x, m, sd)
  return(norm_C)
}

e = 1
dnorm_one_sd_C <- function(x){
  norm_one_sd_C <- dnorm(x, m, sd)
  # Have NA values outside interval x in [e]:
  norm_one_sd_C[x <= e] <- NA
  return(norm_one_sd_C)
}


C <- ggplot(results_matrix_C, aes(x = results_matrix_C$X)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), bins = 10, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm_one_sd_C, geom = "area", fill = "#CE9A05", color = "#CE9A05", alpha = 0.25, size = 1) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm_C, colour = "#CE0539", size = 1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```
## PLOT 2 ##

results_matrix_U <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20)+1, nrow=20))
colnames(results_matrix_U) <- c("X")

m <- mean(results_matrix_U$X)
sd <- sd(results_matrix_U$X)
dnorm_U <- function(x){
  norm_U <- dnorm(x, m, sd)
  return(norm_U)
}

e = 2
dnorm_one_sd_U <- function(x){
  norm_one_sd_U <- dnorm(x, m, sd)
  # Have NA values outside interval x in [e]:
  norm_one_sd_U[x <= e] <- NA
  return(norm_one_sd_U)
}


U <- ggplot(results_matrix_U, aes(x = results_matrix_U$X)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), bins = 10, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm_one_sd_U, geom = "area", fill = "#CE9A05", color = "#CE9A05", alpha = 0.25, size = 1) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm_U, colour = "#CE0539", size = 1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(C, U,
          nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

As you can see in the composite plot, the first one has taken the normal distribution curve of the second plot rather than its own one from my initial plot (Plot 1).

**UPDATE**

Variable "e" refers to the shaded area which is related to the distribution curve.
m = mean of the dataset
sd = standard deviation of the dataset
m and sd are used to generate the normal distribution curves

Comment: I think the issue has nothing to do with plots, and everything to do with the way you define your functions. `dnorm_C` takes only `x` as an argument, but it also uses `m` and `sd`. You may need to `force` them, but better practice would be to pass them in explicitly - skimming your question I'm not really sure what values you want to use (and clearly R isn't sure either). Good reading on this topic is the [functional operators section of Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html). The `dnorm_one_sd_C` is even worse, it uses a constant `e` that I don't see defined anywhere.

Comment: @Gregor, thank you for the response. I have updated the issue you had with `dnorm_one_sd_C`. If the problem is with the function, could you please provide a worked example so that I can fix the problem I have.

Comment: The issue is not that "you don't explain what `e` is", the issue is that your functions use variables like `e` and `m` and `sd` that are not passed in as arguments. My advice is that you should rewrite your `dnorm_one_sd_C <- function(x)` as `dnorm_one_sd_C <- function(x, m, sd)` and rewrite `dnorm_one_sd_U <- function(x)` as `dnorm_one_sd_U <- function(x, m, sd, e)`. If you want explanation of *why* this is a problem and this advice is needed, read the link I posted in my first comment - it is too complicated to explain well here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

By inserting the function in full into the stat_function section of the ggplot2 code, this has worked

i.e:

```
## PLOT 1 ##

results_matrix_C <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=20))
colnames(results_matrix_C) <- c("X")

mean <- mean(results_matrix_C$X)
sd <- sd(results_matrix_C$X)
e = 1


C <- ggplot(results_matrix_C, aes(x = results_matrix_C$X)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), bins = 10, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function( 
    fun = function(x, mean, sd, e){ 
      norm_one_sd_C <- dnorm(x, mean, sd)
      norm_one_sd_C[x <= e] <- NA
  return(norm_one_sd_C)}, 
    args = c(mean = mean, sd = sd, e = e), geom = "area", fill = "#CE9A05", color = "#CE9A05", alpha = 0.25, size = 1) +
  stat_function( 
    fun = function(x, mean, sd){ 
      dnorm(x = x, mean = mean, sd = sd)}, 
    args = c(mean = mean, sd = sd), colour = "#CE0539", size = 1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```
## PLOT 2 ##

results_matrix_U <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20)+1, nrow=20))
colnames(results_matrix_U) <- c("X")

mean <- mean(results_matrix_U$X)
sd <- sd(results_matrix_U$X)
e = 2


U <- ggplot(results_matrix_U, aes(x = results_matrix_U$X)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), bins = 10, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function( 
    fun = function(x, mean, sd, e){ 
      norm_one_sd_U <- dnorm(x, mean, sd)
      norm_one_sd_U[x <= e] <- NA
  return(norm_one_sd_U)}, 
    args = c(mean = mean, sd = sd, e = e), geom = "area", fill = "#CE9A05", color = "#CE9A05", alpha = 0.25, size = 1) +
  stat_function( 
    fun = function(x, mean, sd){ 
      dnorm(x = x, mean = mean, sd = sd)}, 
    args = c(mean = mean, sd = sd), colour = "#CE0539", size = 1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(C, U,
          nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
```

[image]